# How to deal with standard deviation of experimental data in ABC

Tags: bayesian, modeling

I have experimental data points with standard deviations. How does one weight the contribution of each approximation of a parameter using ABC based on how large the SD values are of the experimental data?

I.e. should you be more or less lenient with accepting a parameter value if the standard deviation of the experimental value is large? And if so, how?

EDIT:

I have an experiment to find out how many bacteria $B$, I have on my finger after each contact with a contaminated surface $n$.

[image]

I have a model that predicts how many bacteria I have on my finger after touching $n$ times. $B_n=B_{n-1}+\alpha(B_s-B_{n-1})$. Where B_n is the number of bacteria after contact n. $B_s$ is the surface concentration and $\alpha$ is the parameter to estimate.

How do I take into consideration that my SD values in the experiment are of different magnitude for each n? Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you Xi'an, I've read some of your answers to questions on here and papers about ABC but haven't been able to work out how to deal with the effect that the SD of the experimental (empirical) value have on parameter acceptances. e.g. I have a model that predicts how many bacteria I have on my finger after touching n times. $B_n=B_{n-1}+\alpha(B_s-B_{n-1})$. Where B_n is the number of bacteria after contact n. $B_s$ is the surface concentration and $\alpha$ is the parameter to estimate. I have experimental values for n contacts with their SD but not sure how to treat the SD. Any thoughts?

Comment: The distance part is exactly what I was getting at. So far I have used (prediction-data)/SD_data. What do you think?=

Comment: Hmmm, the model produces SD if we calculate them using a % of accepted alpha values, don't you think?